# Java Long Stream contains specific number

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to check, if a `LongStream` contains a specific number at least once, but not totally consists of this number:

My approach:

```
public static boolean containsNum(LongStream input, int n) {

    return input.anyMatch(i -> i == n);

}
```

Tests:

```
assertEquals(false, containsNum(LongStream.of(1, 2, 3), 19)); // ok
assertEquals(true, containsNum(LongStream.of(1, 2, 3, 19), 19)); //ok
assertEquals(true, containsNum(LongStream.of(1, 19, 19), 19)); //ok
assertEquals(false, containsNum(LongStream.of(1), 19)); //ok
assertEquals(false, containsNum(LongStream.of(19, 19), 19)); // FAIL
assertEquals(false, containsNum(LongStream.of(19), 19)); //FAIL
```

I know that `anyMatch` can´t work in my problem, but the best solution I found. How can I get all tests passing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like a reduce function, as Andy's answer shows, but that would go through the whole stream instead of stopping as soon as you found the number and a different number.

The problem is that those `...Match` methods of streams only look at one element at a time, i.e. you would have to save knowledge about the passed elements in some outside state variable. wero and Roland demonstrate this in their answers.

One possibility without relying on outside state while only checking as many elements as necessary would be:

```
boolean pass = longStream.map(l -> l == number ? 1 : 0)
                         .distinct()
                         .limit(2)
                         .count()
                         == 2;
```

Comment: I suggest to insert a `limit(2)` between `.distinct()` and `.count()`, to get a short-circuiting like behavior, and remove the `AtomicBoolean` variant, as it has no advantage, neither in simplicity nor in efficiency. By the way, if you ever need to deal with `AtomicBoolean` in their intended environment, read multi-threaded, you should learn that `atomicBoolean.set(atomicBoolean.get() || condition)` is broken (search for “check-then-act anti-pattern”). Instead, use `atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(false, condition)`…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the input. I think I know what you are hinting at with the AtomicBoolean, wondered myself but ignored it for now as I just needed a container. I needed a moment to understand why the `limit` would help at all, since we only have two values anyway. If I got it right, it helps because it will "stop" the mapping and distinct check as soon as we have the second values, correct?

Comment: Exactly. We know, there are at most two numbers, but the stream implementation doesn’t know. So specifying the `limit(2)` explicitly, we allow to stop after encountering both values.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the stream, keeping a pair of booleans:

- The first indicating whether you found at least 1 occurrence of n;
- The second indicating whether you found at least 1 occurrence of something other than n.

Let's say you've got some `Pair` class; then:

```
Stream<Pair> pairs =
  input.map(i -> (i == n) ? Pair.of(true, false) : Pair.of(false, true));
```

Then, reduce this stream by or-ing together the two elements:

```
Pair reduces =
    pairs.reduce(
        Pair.of(false, false),
        (a, b) -> Pair.of(a.first || b.first, a.second || b.second));
```

Then check (and return) that both elements are true:

```
return reduced.first && reduced.second;
```

Comment: There are better solutions that do short circuiting, check the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

xD:

```
public static boolean containsNum(LongStream input, int n) {
    LongSummaryStatistics summary = input.map(i -> i == n ? 1 : 0).summaryStatistics();
    return summary.getMax() == 1 && summary.getMin() == 0;
}
```

Explanation:

- `summary.getMax() == 1`: at least one n is found
- `summary.getMin() == 0`: at least one non-n is found

Comment: There are better solutions that do short circuiting, check the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [wero's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44255945/480894) answer:

```
 public static boolean containsNum(LongStream input, int n) {
    final AtomicBoolean different = new AtomicBoolean();
    final AtomicBoolean equals = new AtomicBoolean();
    return input.anyMatch(i -> {
        different.compareAndSet(false, i != n);
        equals.compareAndSet(false, i == n);
        return different.get() && equals.get();
    });
}
```

Comment: this is not atomic... you need to do *both* operations atomically.

Comment: @Eugene why both?

Comment: "check-then-act anti-pattern". by the time you do `get` someone might have already changed the value there.

Comment: @Eugene If you analyze the code you will see that due to the `compareAndSet` the value of each `AtomicBoolean` can only change from `false` to `true`. Once set to true it will stay that way.

Comment: indeed! I admit that once I've seen the two variables being updated, wrote a rushed comment. Sorry. *Generally* this could fail and has to be done atomically (like you know.. a spin lock in my answer); but in this problem, IMO you are fine. Thx for making me think about this twice!

Answer (score -2):

Keep track if you have seen `n` and non `n`:

```
public static boolean containsNum(LongStream input, int n) {
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[2]; 
    return input.anyMatch(i -> { seen[i==n ? 0 : 1] = true; return seen[0] && seen[1]; });
}
```

Comment: @wero I wasn't the downvoter (promise!), but perhaps the DV'er was objecting to the fact it's not thread safe? `input` could be a parallel stream.

Comment: @wero because you don't guarantee visibility of the updates to the array.

Comment: Look at my answer for threadsafe version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44258286/480894

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's *not* wrong, it violates a rule. If you `never` run this in parallel you might never see wrong results. I agree with you, but the wording is not entirely correct.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I don't really care about the naming here... My point was that `This answer is plain wrong` is a bit rough...